# Allocating memory for a sparse matrix in CUDA in hybrid (HYB) format?

Tags: c++, matrix, memory-management, cuda, nvidia

I have a matrix in C00 format, which I convert to CSR format via the following code:

```
status = cusparseXcoo2csr(handle, cooRowIndex, nnz, n, 
    csrRowPtr, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);
```

I then want to convert the matrix from CSR format to HYB format, but I am not sure how much memory I need to allocate for the matrix in HYB format. I've looked online and can't find any resources on this. How much memory should be allocated?

Here is what I plan to use for converting from csr to hyb format:

```
cusparseScsr2hyb(handle_array[i], m, n, 
        descr, 
        cooVal,
        csrRowPtr, 
        cooColIndex, 
        hybA, 
        CUSPARSE_HYB_PARTITION_AUTO);
```

Here is my code for allocating memory, but I'm not sure what to add to allocate memory for hybA.

```
cudaStat1 = cudaMalloc((void**)&cooRowIndex, nnz*sizeof(cooRowIndex[0])); // Row indices for A
cudaStat2 = cudaMalloc((void**)&cooColIndex, nnz*sizeof(cooColIndex[0])); // Column indices for A
cudaStat3 = cudaMalloc((void**)&cooVal, nnz*sizeof(cooVal[0]));           // Data values for A
cudaStat4 = cudaMalloc((void**)&csrRowPtr, (n + 1)*sizeof(csrRowPtr[0]));
```

Comment: cusparse HYB format is [an opaque type](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparsehybmatt).  You don't allocate manually for it.  Study [this](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-dev/src/mat/impls/aij/seq/seqcusparse/aijcusparse.cu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RobertCrovella for his comment.

Here is how a hybrid matrix is used:

First Create the hybrid matrix object:

```
cusparseHybMat_t hybA;
cusparseCreateHybMat(&hybA);
```

Then convert your coo matrix to csr format:

```
status = cusparseXcoo2csr(handle, cooRowIndex, nnz, m, 
        csrRowPtr, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);
```

Then convert your csr matrix to hyb format:

```
cusparseScsr2hyb(handle, m, n, descr, cooVal,
            csrRowPtr, cooColIndex, hybA_array[i], 
            0, CUSPARSE_HYB_PARTITION_AUTO);
```

Then perform the sparse matrix * dense vector operation:

```
status = cusparseShybmv(handle,CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, &alpha, 
    descr, hybA, &xVal[0], &beta, &y[0]);
```